# Wrapping a code block around code in VIM

Tags: vim

Is it possible to wrap a code block around a piece of code in VIM? For example, if I want to wrap a while loop around the following, how can I do it without having to scroll to the bottom of the code to add the closing brace:

```
if(z > y)
{
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
             addPoint();
             break;
        case 2:
             addValue();
             break;
    }
}
```

This is what the code will look like afterwards:

```
while (a > 10)
{
    if(z > y)
    {
        switch(x)
        {
             case 1:
                 addPoint();
                 break;
             case 2:
                 addValue();
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, give us an "after" state. What you want sounds trivial but… better safe than sorry.

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697

Comment: @Kevin put it as an answer I will vote. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the vim plugin [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697). It lets you wrap lines or fragments in blocks (and change the wrapping pairs).

Answer (score 6):

Vim does not have a built in surrounding system. I suggust you look at Tim Pope's excellent [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin. Then assuming you are positioned on the `if` you can do this:

```
Vj%SBIwhile (a > 10)
```

- The `Vj%` selects the block + the conditional.
- `SB` surrounds the selected text with a `{`,`}` (read surround with block)
- Insert your loop text at the beginning of the newly inserted block.

You don't need surround to do this. You can do it with plain vanilla vim.

```
Vj%>`]o}<esc>g;g;Owhile (a > 10)<cr>{<esc>
```

However I prefer to use surround as it is a very handy plugin to have.

For more help see:

```
:h %
:h g;
:h `]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check something like Snipmate, it's possible they have an ability of surrounding Visually selected code with a snippit.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

> *snipMate-visual-selection-support* There is a special placeholder called {VISUAL}. If you visually select text, then press  Vim
>   switches to insert mode. The next snippet you'll expand will replace
>   {VISUAL} by the text which was selected previously

Answer (score 0):

You can make a mapping to do this in vanilla Vim e.g.:

```
:imap <S-F2> <Esc>j>>j>%%o<C-D>}
```

Use the mapped key after typing the opening brace for the surrounding code. Goes without saying that you should change `<S-F2>` to a keymap you like.

---

Breakdown of the key sequence:

<kbd>Esc</kbd>: go to Normal mode

<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd>: move cursor to next line (in your example the `if` line) and indent it.

<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>%</kbd>: move cursor to the line with opening brace of `if`, indent from there to matching brace (the cursor will jump back to the opening brace)

<kbd>%</kbd> goes to the closing brace of `if`

<kbd>o</kbd> add a new line after the closing brace, and enter Insert mode.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: unindent (to undo the effect of smartindent)

<kbd>}</kbd> add the closing brace for the surround code (in your example, `while`)

---

Of course the plugins recommended by others have many more features so you should look at those as well.

Comment: Again this is very useful. Thank you for your contribution to the question.