# With Vim, how can I wrap properly a code with a JavaScript function argument?

Tags: javascript, vim

I want to easily wrap my code in an argument. For example:

```
1 + 1;
```

I want this to be in `console.log()` after wrapping:

```
console.log(1+1);
```

I tried using Surround Vim, but it's for HTML and not really suitable for JavaScript, because it does not move semicolon which is wrapped :

`V` for select entire line.
`S` for enter in

```
console.log(1 + 1;)
```

Do you know a better way or Vim plugin ?

This link does not apply to my specific case :
[Wrapping a code block around code in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281557/wrapping-a-code-block-around-code-in-vim)

I'm learning Vim 9 (in terminal). I'm going back to learning programming (with JS and soon PHP).

Comment: Surround.vim is not *"for HTML"* - or any specific language for that matter.

Comment: Ah, right @Friedrich.

Answer (score 5):

`V` puts you into *visual-line* mode. If you don't want to operate on the whole line, then there is no point using it.

In this case, you should use plain visual mode, with `v`, and an appropriate motion:

```
vt;            " visually select till semicolon
S              " trigger Surround
f              " enter "function" sub-mode
console.log    " type name of function
<CR>           " press enter
```

or you could bypass visual mode entirely:

```
yst;           " surround till semicolon
f              " enter "function" sub-mode
console.log    " type name of function
<CR>           " press enter
```

See `:help ys` (assuming Surround was installed properly), `:help visual-mode`, `:help t`, an `:help navigation` in general.

FWIW, this is how you would do it *without* Surround:

```
ct;            " change till semicolon
console.log(   " insert function name and opening parenthesis
<C-r>"         " insert changed text
)              " insert closing parenthesis
<Esc>          " leave insert mode
```

See `:help c` and `:help i_ctrl-r`.

Comment: Nicely perfect, It works, the three approaches are interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question *"do you know a better way?"*

I'd just do

```
Iconsole.log(<Esc>$i)<Esc>
```

Insert "console.log(" at the start of the line, jump to the end and insert the closing parenthesis before the semi-colon. Just text editing.

Technically, that's *two* insertions so you would e.g. have to press `uu` to undo both of them. This is a caveat and I'd happily ignore it.

A slightly more complicated way to do it (and only worthwhile if you want to operate on several lines at once) is to use the `:substitute` command like this

```
:[range]s/\s*\zs.*\ze;/console.log(&)/
```

Where `[range]` is the lines to operate on (leave out for current line only).

Our actual match is *anything* or `.*`, contained in `\zs` and `\ze` to mark the start and end of match, respectively. Everything outside is not captured, that's leading whitespace (if any) and the trailing semi-colon.

This is replaced by "console.log()" with our captured match `&` inserted between the parentheses.

For reference, see [`:help substitute`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute), [`:help /\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) and [`:help s/\&`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#s%2F%5C%26).

Comment: Simple (for de 1st part) and effective, thank you a lot